# Using a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm working on a program that calls on a method from another class, and I can't seem to get past that road bump. The example I'm using simply sets a variable in the main method equal to the other class, and the major error I'm getting in my own program is that the symbol I'm using can't be found - I've also looked at other similar questions on here, but I can't wrap my head around on how to use the answers in my own program.

Here a portion of my main method, called MyTriangle:

```
do
  {
     System.out.print ("Enter the first of a triangle: ");
     side1 = scan.nextDouble();

     System.out.print ("Enter the second side of a triangle: ");
     side2 = scan.nextDouble();

     System.out.print ("Enter the third side of a triangle: ");
     side3 = scan.nextDouble();

     validity = isValid (side1, side2, side3);

     if (validity == true)
     {  
        System.out.println ("Area of the triangle is " + area);
     }

     if (validity == false)
     {
        System.out.println ("Invalid input");
     }   

     System.out.print ("\nContinue? <y/n> ");
     end = scan.next();

  } while (!end.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
```

And here's a portion of my class TestMyTriangle:

```
public class TestMyTriangle
{

 public static double area (double side1, double side2, double side3)
 {
    double resultArea = 0;

    double sum = 0;

    sum = ((side1 + side2 + side3) / 2);

    resultArea = Math.sqrt(sum * ((sum - side1) * (sum - side2) * (sum -side3)));

    return resultArea;
 }        
}
```

The way I'm invoking TestMyTriangle is identical to the example I'm using, but it's still not working. If anyone can help me see what I'm missing, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How are you invoking the method? Also, post the relevant stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

If the error is coming from the code samples you posted, my bet would be that your `isValid` method is in the `TestMyTriangle` class. So, in order to invoke `isValid`, you must write it like so:

```
validity = TestMyTriangle.isValid(side1, side2, side3);
```

Also make sure that when you call area, you also reference the class like so:

```
System.out.println("Area of the triangle is " + TestMyTriangle.area(side1, side2, side3));
```

Lastly, IF your two files are not in the same directory, make sure to import the other class file like so:

```
import path/to/directory/TestMyTriangle;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
System.out.println ("Area of the triangle is " + area);
```

to this:

```
System.out.println ("Area of the triangle is " + TestMyTriangle.area(side1, side2, side3));
```